# Storing big chunks of text in a List, how to break a line for better view at powershell?

Tags: python-2.7, list, powershell

I'd like to make a list with some phrases, and then using the randint to print one of them randomly with powershell.
I can do it, but it'll look really bad.
My problem is, it is really big lines so it won't look "decent" at it, I want to break the lines somehow so I wouldn't have to scroll sideways to read everything.

`scene = ["lots of stuff", "lots of stuff 2", "lots of stuff 3"]`

So let's say I wanna break each of those elements after 'of', but still want to keep `scene[0] = "lots of stuff"` only with the line break when running the program at **powershell**. Is it possible?

Comment: In PowerShell you can just pipe to `Out-String -Width ##` and it will wrap text at whatever you want it to.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician  `Out-String -Width` specifies the number of characters in each line of output. [Any additional characters are **truncated**, not wrapped.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-String)

Comment: @JosefZ They don't actually get truncated, but at the same time it doesn't seem to work very well on external commands, so I don't know if it would work here. Try `Help gci | Out-String -Width 20` and you'll see that it wraps, it does not truncate.

Comment: Looked up those commands but the best way I could find was going on Properties and using those to adjust the \n with the window size.